# Не работает tabs в Bootstrap 5 с Django

Tags: html, django, bootstrap

Не могу понять почему не работают вкладки.

Нажимаю на первую вкладку и ни чего не происходит. Третья работает и отображает текст.
Страницы первой и второй вкладки написаны отдельными файлами которые подгружаются динамически.

С веб особо не работал раньше, так как основная деятельность на С++.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs mb-3" id="ex-with-icons" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item active" role="presentation">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="id_nomenclature" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="{% url 'nomenclature' %}" role="tab"
                aria-current="page" aria-controls="id_nomenclature_pane" aria-selected="true">
                <img class="img-thumbnail me-1" src="{% static 'images/bootstrap-icons/list-ul.svg' %}" alt="Bootstrap" width="24" height="24">
                Номенклатура
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
          <a class="nav-link" id="id_add_product" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="{% url 'add_product' %}" role="tab"
            aria-controls="id_add_product_pane" aria-selected="false">Добавить товар</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
          <a class="nav-link" id="ex-with-icons-tab-3" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#ex-with-icons-tabs-3" role="tab"
            aria-controls="ex-with-icons-tabs-3" aria-selected="false"><i class="fas fa-cogs fa-fw me-2"></i>Settings</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
      <!-- Tabs navs -->
      
      <!-- Tabs content -->
    
    <div class="tab-content" id="tab-content">
        {% block content_product %}
        {% endblock content_product %}

        <!-- <div class="tab-pane fade" id="ex-with-icons-tabs-2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="ex-with-icons-tab-2">
          Tab 2 content
        </div> -->
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="ex-with-icons-tabs-3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="ex-with-icons-tab-3">
          Tab 3 content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Код номенклатуры

```
{% extends "Products/products.html" %}

{% block content_product %}
<h1 class="page-header">Товар</h1>
<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="id_nomenclature_pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="id_nomenclature">
    <div class="row">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">Имя</th>
                    <th scope="col">Фамилия</th>
                    <th scope="col">Обращение</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">2</th>
                    <td>Jacob</td>
                    <td>Thornton</td>
                    <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">3</th>
                    <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
                    <td>@twitter</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content_product %}
```